# Fill an area inside two CubicCurve2D.Float s and a line

Tags: java, scala, graphics2d

I'm drawing a tab in a user interface.  I have the outline as I want it.  How do I fill the area?

This is the code that draws the border of the tab:

```
val g2 = g.asInstanceOf[Graphics2D]

g2.translate(x, y)
val q = new CubicCurve2D.Float
q.setCurve(0, h, 8, h, 6, 0, 16, 0)
g2.setColor(Color.RED)
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)
g2.draw(q)
val end = w - 8
g2.drawLine(17, 0, end, 0)
q.setCurve(end, 0, end+10, 0, w, h, w + 8, h)
g2.draw(q)
```

and this is the line it draws (the red one): [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T62Ay.jpg)

I would like to be able to fill the inside of the red line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Scala, but in Java 2D, the Graphics2D object can fill or draw the outline of any [Shape](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) object. For some arbitrary shape you would define it with [GeneralPath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html) object, such as:

```
GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
path.lineTo(10, 10);
path.lineTo(0, 10);
path.lineTo(0, 0);
graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
graphics.fill(path);
```

The GeneralPath object also has methods for drawing bezier curves and quads, so you would draw the path and then choose to fill or draw the outline of it.

Added new link to [GeneralPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I looked at GeneralPath and it pointed me towards Path2D.Float, which I used by adding my CubicCurve2D.Float s to. I can then draw and fill the Path2D.Float as suggested.

Comment: What does `lineTo()` with cubic curves  and **CubicCurve2D.Float** ???